# PHP - Sharing large (static) data between instances (without using SQL)

Tags: php, html, performance, shared-memory

**TL;DR** – What's the *simplest* approach to very quickly loading large files (~tens of MB) in PHP to avoid responsiveness issues in a web page? For example, I suspect I'll need to do something like pre-loading the files and sharing the resulting large (static) associative arrays from one PHP instance to the instances created by the web server. I'm specifically trying to *avoid* having to deal with SQL...

**Details**

I've put together an online dictionary ([here](https://old-norse.net/search.php)) with a home-brew search engine that works beautifully on my local computer, but has performance problems on the server. (Note: I have no control over the server aside from updating my own files.)

The performance problems are largely due to the index files that I need to load (large associative arrays, json encoded). These are on the order of 6-16 MB and only those required for the specific type of search are loaded. This means non-typical searches (e.g., searching specifically in quotes or etymology) show a significant performance hit due to the necessity of loading extra (large) files.

Now, I realize many people will tell me that I should be using SQL or some other DB solution instead of loading and searching my own index files.  They're correct, but right now I don't have the time or energy to fight with learning how to roll my own SQL server, converting all my data structures over to SQL format, and figuring out how to interface PHP with SQL, etc. I have no experience with SQL and all the tutorials I've looked at so far make it seem ill suited to my data structures (i.e., I can't define my records in terms of fixed-width strings because I have arbitrary length blocks of text for every entry and arbitrary numbers of entries associated with a given headword, etc.)

Again, my current code works perfectly on my local computer - all the problems boil down to the time expensive step of loading these large index files. **A "simple" fix (that allows me to keep my current design) would seem to be pre-loading these index files in a separate script and then have any PHP instances created by the web server access these static data structures that already exist in memory** (again, they're just a bunch of large/complex associative arrays).  These data structures/files are static, so locking/race conditions aren't an issue (i.e., the data only changes periodically when I push out updates with corrections/updated inflection lists, etc.).

I've attempted to find information on how to approach this, but the results are confusing and contradictory and are beyond the scope of things I've worked with before. I'm happy to learn new things, but it's not clear which path will even work for what I'm trying to do.

1. Lot's of (older?) recommendations to use ACP, but I see comments that this only works for instances on the same processor - so even if they're on the same server it may not work (even worse, maybe the host server will spread different instances across different virtual machines). I also see comments that some aspects of ACP are deprecated as well as discussions about re-compiling PHP with various flags - this is obviously not an option for me; I only have what's available on the server.
2. A recommendation to use built in IPC functions within PHP ([link](https://re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-shared-memory-segments-ipc)) - but it's not clear if I can carve out a ~50 MB chunk to share (the way it's written makes it sound like this is for small chunks of memory) and some of the comments suggest there can memory collision problems or that this would cause performance issues and a daemon/socket approach (see comments at the end of the linked article).  Honestly, this approach looks appealing as I can just use my existing data structures.  However, I'm worried this will have the same problems as those leveled at APC (e.g., will this work if the server is putting different instances on different virtual machines?)
3. Daemon/socket approach - a comment in the link above claims this would be best performance-wise. I haven't worked with sockets before, but I feel like it would be less painful to learn this than restructuring everything around an SQL approach (maybe that's a bad assessment on my part?) I can at least conceptualize how this would work, but I would need to learn how to get a daemon script that's always running in the background and ensure it's responsive to multiple simultaneous instances, etc.

I'm sure there are other approaches that I haven't yet stumbled across.

Again, ideally, I'd like an approach that simply lets me load all the index files and hang those associative arrays out in the wind for everyone to look at.  Security's not an issue (it's just a processed version of the data in the simple web pages) and the data is static.

Note: the web server is running PHP 7.4 (Zend 3.4) and my local environment is OSX 10.14 or 10.15 with PHP 7.3 (Zend 3.3)

Comment: SQL - Especially SQLite/Mysql, is not that hard to learn and probably is faster to learn as any other approach you try here, as all those things you try, seems to be some kind of DB in the end. And Mysql is available almost everywhere, with zillions of tutorials for that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to store your large objects. It is [well supported in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php). You will need to increase the maximum object size, the default is 1MB, but this is a simple configuration option.